# Какой вариант задачи этого вопроса правильный?

Tags: прямая-речь

1.1. Помоги, пожалуйста. В данном предложении: "Каждый день я всё продолжала(,) и продолжала" - нужна запятая?

1.2. Помоги, пожалуйста. В данном предложении "Каждый день я всё продолжала(,) и продолжала" нужна запятая?

1.3. Помоги, пожалуйста. В данном предложении "каждый день я всё продолжала(,) и продолжала"  нужна запятая?

А если мы слово *данном* уберём-таки?

1.1. Помоги, пожалуйста. В предложении: "Каждый день я всё продолжала(,) и продолжала" - нужна запятая?

1.2. Помоги, пожалуйста. В предложении "Каждый день я всё продолжала(,) и продолжала" нужна запятая?

1.3. Помоги, пожалуйста. В предложении "каждый день я всё продолжала(,) и продолжала"  нужна запятая?

Answer (score 0):

«Немало трудностей возникает при пунктуационном оформлении текстов разговорной речи».  И чем путанее речь, тем больше трудностей.
«Для решения вопроса о знаках препинания» в текстах, передающих разговорную речь «приходится искать особые критерии».
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=198
Советы мастеров слова чаще всего сводятся к тому, что при записи «устной разговорной речи» выбор варианта ставить / не ставить знак препинания зависит от интонации, которую необходимо передать (читателю).
В большинстве случаев у писателя есть возможность перефразировать высказывание, чтобы упростить проблему записи и, что еще важнее, - облегчить читателю понимание написанного.
Например:
Помогите, пожалуйста, обосновать постановку запятой в предложении: «Каждый день я все продолжала(,) и продолжала».

Comment: В оформлении разговорной речи важно все: семантика, грамматика, интонация, стилистика. В приведенных примерах надо проверить  текст во всех отношениях и только тогда переходить к проверке пунктуации. Вот и нет ответов: смысл неясен, ситуация непонятна, кто, где и зачем это говорит. Какие уж тут запятые.